# Почему при ковариантности происходит upcast?

Tags: c#, делегаты

При ковариантности обобщенных делегатов становится возможным возвращение более производного типа из метода сигнатуры делегата. Но где в этом месте происходит upcast, если мы возвращаем более производный тип?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Апкаст это приведение ссылки на объект к типу родителя. Не понял вопроса. Звучит как "при вычислении результата сложения 2 и 2 происходит сложение, но где именно оно происходит?". Что именно непонятно? Апкаст это примитивная магипуляция, и может выполняться неявно при обычном присваивании или возврате из метода, ничего необычного, возврат из метода это по сути тоже присваивание результату работы метода определенного значения.